# Extend Keycloak session timeout for specific users

Tags: session, keycloak, session-timeout

I was wondering is it possible to extend a session timeout for specific users in a Keycloak?

I read a documentation and looks like it doesn't has this feature, however I might be wrong.

Also, I noticed it has an offline_token which has a longer expiration time, and I wonder if for some users I could use it instead of a normal refresh token. However not sure if it is a good idea, since user session would still expire, but application could continue making API calls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried checking authentication time from the token and use prompt=login

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and it asks user for login details again, and surprisingly after entering them it doesn't reset session start time. Perhaps I am doing something wrong. I tried using: ".../protocol/openid-connect/auth?&prompt=login"